# Different footer for each chapter

Tags: header-footer

I would like to have a different custom footer for each chapter. For e.g each chapter has a version, i would like to print that version for that chapter in the footer.

Comment: The way to do this would be to define the page footer so that it uses a mark or a macro --- set the mark or redefine the macro at the beginning of each chapter, depending on the desired content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package, you can easily place the version at the footer. The following example illustrates this (details may vary depending on how you actually define the version). I used a `\ChapVersion` command to be used at the beginning of chapters, to hold the chapter version; internally, this version is placed at the footer:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ChapVersion[1]{\def\@ChapVersion{#1}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small\@ChapVersion}% footer center: version
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\thepage}% header (left on even, right on odd): page number
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\ChapVersion{Version 2.3--April 25, 2009}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\ChapVersion{Version 1.1--September 13, 2012}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]