# Change the footer for each chapter

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am laying out a book and need to have a different custom footer for each chapter.  For instance, the page below has a footer that says "Flashbacks Chapter 3 1982" and for the next chapter I need to change the style to "Flashbacks Chapter 4 1983".
A similar question was asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123574/different-footer-for-each-chapter) but I can't quite figureout how to modify mine.

Here is a MWE where both chapters have 'Chapter 3' in the footer:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\footnotesize{Author}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{Title \hspace{2mm}|\hspace{2mm}  CHAPTER 3  \hspace{2mm}|\hspace{2mm}  1982}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\texttt{{\footnotesize{{\scriptsize\thepage}}}}}

%----------------------DOCUMENT----------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\chapter*{{\small {\textsf{\bfseries{Chapter 3}}}}}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
Example Text
\chapter*{{\small {\textsf{\bfseries{Chapter 4}}}}}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
Example Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get why you use the starred version `\chapter` while numbering them?

Comment: In order to remove the numbering the actually text.  i.e. 'Downloaded' not 'Chapter 3: Downloaded"

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. You want the chapter title does not contain the label `chapter xx`, only the title (Downloaded in the present case) but the footer must contain both the label and the title? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: That's correct.  The chapter # in the title itself is replaced by the big number in the background.

Comment: So really, you want a numbered chapter, w but with this special layout, i.e; a big chapter number in the back ground and the title, and an ordinary `flashbacks |chapter xx |  some year`in the footer?

Comment: I didn't make the design, I'm just putting it together, but yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to boil down to setting footers in a dynamic fashion (regardless of the document content). As such, below I've defined the three components of the footer as `\TITLE`, `\CHAPTER` and `\YEAR`, which can be set whenever needed using `\settitle`, `\setchapter` and `\setyear` respectively:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\footnotesize{Author}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\TITLE \hspace{2mm} $\vert$ \hspace{2mm} \CHAPTER \hspace{2mm} $\vert$ \hspace{2mm} \YEAR}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\texttt{\scriptsize\thepage}}

\newcommand{\settitle}[1]{\def\TITLE{#1}}
\newcommand{\setchapter}[1]{\def\CHAPTER{#1}}
\newcommand{\setyear}[1]{\def\YEAR{#1}}
\newcommand{\chapterfont}{\small\sffamily\bfseries}

%----------------------DOCUMENT----------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}

\chapter*{\chapterfont Chapter 3}
\settitle{Title A}\setchapter{CHaPTeR 3}\setyear{1982}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
Example Text

\chapter*{\chapterfont Chapter 4}
\settitle{Title B}\setchapter{CHaPTeR 4}\setyear{1983}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
Example Text

\end{document}
```